# WordPress : error while fetching post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm fetching posts in home page like this

```
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;                
            twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
    ?>

<?php // get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
```

it prints post but also prints this message before posts :

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>

‘ . ‘Read More’.’ ‘; ?>
```

see attached screenshot for output of post [image]

Comment: What's your question? What's the error message?

Comment: The issue is probably in one of your "template parts"

Comment: which file should i check for this ? i'm new to wordpress

Comment: Looks like you're missing an opening PHP tag. I'd suggest check the files with the name `content` at the beginning in your theme folder; one of them is being included via the `get_template_part()` function.

Comment: i just posted content.php here   pastebin.com/C3mfWqjq

Comment: I don't know anything about your theme...but it sounds like the issue is in *content-page.php*

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to search the theme folder and search for the code that is problematic. If you don't need it delete it, if you do need it use correct php.

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>

‘ . ‘Read More’.’ ‘; ?>
```

The problem is it is printing the code as text because it is not using the php opening tag